# how to show the number taken by user that how much time it is entered by user

Tags: c++

Ok the program seems to be easy while doing with loops but what about if else if and else is it possible to do it with these conditions
I have tried and here is my effort but am failed totally failed .

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
int main(){
    using namespace std;
    int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l;
    int c1=0;
    int c2=0;
    int c3=0;
    int c4=0;
    cout<<"please enter first number\n";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"please enter second number\n";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"please enter third number\n";
    cin>>c;
    cout<<"please enter fourth number\n";
    cin>>d;
    cout<<"please enter fifth number\n";
    cin>>e;
    cout<<"please enter sixth number\n";
    cin>>f;
    cout<<"please enter seventh number\n";
    cin>>g;
    cout<<"please enter eighth number\n";
    cin>>h;
    cout<<"please enter ninth number\n";
    cin>>j;
    cout<<"please enter tenth number\n";
    cin>>k;
    cout<<"please enter eleventh number\n";
    cin>>l;
    if(a==1)
    {
        c1=a+1;

    }
    else if (a==1 && b==1)
    {
        c2=a+b;
    }
    else if (a==1 && b==1 && c==1)
    {
        c3=a+b+c;
    }
    else if (a==4)
    {
        c4=a+1;
    }
    cout<<"no of 1's="<<c1;
getch();
}
```

i am taking values and after taking values i want to show that 1 appears how much time

Comment: please rephrase your question, it's very vague what you're trying to achieve and it's hard to guess how to help you

Comment: Also have you noticed that `else if (a==1 ...` will never pass the test? `a==1` is handled in the first `if` statement.

Comment: yes i know and i have think alot thats why i came here to ask

Comment: That `abusing namespace std;` inside `main()` doesn't look good...

Comment: @syedshah I didn't say it's not working. I said it's ugly, unidiomatic and should be avoided.

Comment: please stop calling everyone 'bro'... not e.o. is a guy around here...

Comment: ok i will avoid but right now if u can help please help me out

Comment: but why do you want to do it like this and not with a loop? is there a specific reason or are you experimenting with s.t?

Comment: who knows the truth they act upon and who don't know they always make reasons this and this

Comment: wow, that text have just smashed my visual parser completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count how many `ones` you have in your letter variables you can do like this:

```
int c1=0;

if(a==1)
{
    c1++;
}
if (b==1)
{
    c1++;
}

    ...

if (l==1)
{
    c1++;
}
cout<<"no of 1's="<<c1;
```

Comment: thats look really fine

Comment: i am sure that it will work .

Answer (score 3):

Use a loop to enter `N` numbers. While you read them (make sure to check for errors of course), count the number of times you get a number of 1.

Comment: bro it's easy with loop but i wana do with if else condtion

Comment: what's your reason to avoid a loop? imho it's the most readable/understandable variant to do this...

Comment: Then use a sequence "std::cin >> num; if (num == 1) ++cnt; etc etc."

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include <array>
#include <unordered_map>
int main(){
    using namespace std;

    static const int cCount = 11;
    array<int, cCount> values;
    static const array<std::string, cCount> numbers = {
      "first",
      "second",
```

...

```
      "eleventh"}; 

    for (int = 0; i < cCount; ++i) {
      cout<<"please enter " << numbers[i] << " number\n";
      cin>> values[i];
    }  


    unordered_map<int, int> counts;
    for (int = 0; i < cCount; ++i) {
      ++counts[values[i]];
    }
    cout << "no of 1's=" << counts[1];
    getch();
}
```

Comment: you could count the `ones` inside the first loop

Comment: I know, I just wanted to keep similar structure to the original code.

Comment: sure, you could count the 1's in the first loop - or you could write the program in a generic way such that you can retrieve the number of times *any* input was entered using a hashmap. Johny and I essentially gave the same answer.

Answer (score -2):

Wow, what a mess.

use a hashtable, the key is the user input and the value is an unsigned (this unsigned will keep track of how many times the user input the value with the corresponding key). Whenever the user inputs a value, increment the value at that key. Then, at the end, return the value stored at key == '1'.